# Custom radioButton on swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to do a custom radio button for my app project, but swiftui's selector doesnt support a custom radio button. is there a a way to turn my custom design button into a custom radion button??

i tried using a state, but stuck with the logic of it. and search some articles, didnt get the result that i one

if there's an article about it, please do send it. Thank you
[image: the design]

```
struct DisplaySoal: View {
    //@State private var activeView: currentView = currentView.center
    //@State private var isDragging:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
               ScrollView {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(height:500)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                HStack {
                    Text("Jawaban")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding()
                jwbanButton()
                jwbanButton()
                jwbanButton()
                jwbanButton()
                }
                Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct jwbanButton: View {
    @State var isPushed:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isPushed.toggle()
        }) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .foregroundColor(isPushed ? .blue : .gray)
                .frame(height:100)
                .overlay(
                    HStack{
                        Group{
                            Text("A")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.leading)
                            Text("Makan apa ya yang bagus buat kesehatan dan mencegaj seseorang melakukan kejahatan yang akan menahan rasa sakit")
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                )
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean of **selector** could you please give more information or code about it? thank you

Answer (score 2):

```swift
class RadioButtons : ObservableObject {
    
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var isSelected = false
    var title = "Makan apa ya yang bagus buat kesehatan dan mencegaj seseorang melakukan kejahatan yang akan menahan rasa sakit"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var radio_1 = RadioButtons()
    @ObservedObject var radio_2 = RadioButtons()
    @ObservedObject var radio_3 = RadioButtons()
    @ObservedObject var radio_4 = RadioButtons()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            ScrollView {
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(height:500)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Jawaban")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding()
                
                VStack{
                    
                    jwbanButton(isPushed:radio_1.isSelected,title: radio_1.title,id: radio_1.id) {
                        
                        radio_1.isSelected = true
                        radio_2.isSelected = false
                        radio_3.isSelected = false
                        radio_4.isSelected = false
                    }
                    jwbanButton(isPushed:radio_2.isSelected,title: radio_2.title,id: radio_2.id) {
                        
                        radio_1.isSelected = false
                        radio_2.isSelected = true
                        radio_3.isSelected = false
                        radio_4.isSelected = false
                    }
                    jwbanButton(isPushed:radio_3.isSelected,title: radio_3.title,id: radio_3.id) {
                        
                        radio_1.isSelected = false
                        radio_2.isSelected = false
                        radio_3.isSelected = true
                        radio_4.isSelected = false
                    }
                    jwbanButton(isPushed:radio_4.isSelected,title: radio_4.title,id: radio_4.id) {
                        
                        radio_1.isSelected = false
                        radio_2.isSelected = false
                        radio_3.isSelected = false
                        radio_4.isSelected = true
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
}

struct jwbanButton: View {
    
    var isPushed:Bool
    var title:String
    var id:UUID
    let onDetail: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            
            onDetail()
            
        }) {
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .foregroundColor(isPushed ? .blue : .gray)
                .frame(height:100)
                .overlay(
                    HStack{
                        Group{
                            Text("A")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.leading)
                            Text(title)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                )
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is user will have 50 radio button horizontally scrollable in future, this will require lot of re-work, and duplication. Even if this approach works, it will not be optimal for future changes.

Comment: i;m planing to do like 4 * 20, it wouldnt be good tbh, but thanks

Comment: is there a way to automate it?i dont want to create 20 pages and set each page a state